# What does "woo'ed away into" means?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does to be "woo'ed away into" means ? Especially in this sentence :

> would he be woo'ed away into the society?

The [context](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/51012/30201) is to come to a pilgrimage without really knowing if the organisation is a tendentious and proselyte one.

I don't grab it because first [by looking for synonyms](http://www.synonymy.com/synonym.php?word=woo&x=0&y=0) I guess that "to be woo" means to be charmed, attracted ... Then I guessed that wooed away would be quite the reverse ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The apostrophe is surplus to requirements, & may possibly hinder your search.

Verb Woo. Past tense wooed.

Think of 'to be wooed' away as 'to be enticed' away [by promise of some 'reward' for doing so].

The [OLD](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/woo) has past tense examples right at the top

> Seek the favour, support, or custom of.
>   *‘pop stars are being wooed by film companies eager to sign them up’*
>
> Try to gain the love of (someone), especially with a view to marriage.
>   *‘he wooed her with quotes from Shakespeare’*

Answer (score 1):

In business contexts, you will see the verb **woo away** used figuratively to refer to situations where a company is trying to get an employee to  leave their current employer and join them

> Acme Widgets is trying to woo the CTO of Spacely Sprockets away.
>
> Acme Widgets is trying to woo away the CTO of Spacely Sprockets.

Acme Widgets wants to hire the Spacely Sprockets CTO, and has made  blandishments to attract the CTO.